# Одинаково ли компиляторы оптимизируют работу с локальными и статическими переменными?

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Для примера два образца кода:

```
int c=0;
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {...;++c;}
```

.

```
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {...;static int c;++c;}
```

Есть ли различия в скорости их выполнения ?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что компилятор выкинет оба этих ненужных цикла...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В каком смысле "выкинет"?

Comment: В прямом. Не будет цикла, а в c будет записано сразу 100. Возможно, даже не будет переменной c. Компилятор увидит, что цикл можно выкинуть и выкинет. А если c нигде не используется больше - и ее тоже.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Естественно, в цикле делается что-то ещё кроме ++c

Comment: Совсем не очевидно что там есть что-то еще, особенно если речь идет об "оптимизации" инкремента. Вы можете скомпилить оба варианта и посмотреть какой код получается и на основании этого выбрать более оптимальный (по скорости или размеру) вариант.

Comment: @Nokolay1979 Если c и i идут одинаково, то одну из этих переменных компилятор запросто может выкинуть. Я только вчера разбирал тут порос про компиляцию, там постоянно шло обращение к массиву arr[j+g], и j при этом монотонно росло. Оптимизатор просто выкинул переменную g и вел в регистре вообще j+g

Comment: Изменил вопрос, теперь не должно выкидывать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, компиляторы могут поступать в таких случаях по своему усмотрению, в определенных пределах. Статические переменные не используются в программах просто так, могут использоваться повторно и теоретически в разных частях кода. Ваш цикл может передать какой нибудь вызываемой функции указатель на статическую переменную и через этот указатель к ней можно будет обращаться даже после завершения цикла. В связи с этим оптимизатор очень аккуратно подходит к операциям с ней.

По результатам проведенных тестов, оптимизатор GCC в первом случае:

```
int c=0;
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {...;++c;}
```

Не стал выделять память под переменные `i` и `c`, а использовал 1 регистр процессора для ведения одного значения, т.е. он понял, что значения переменных на всех итерациях совпадают и одну из них просто выкинул.

Во втором случае:

```
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {...;static int c;++c;}
```

компилятор выделил под переменную `c` память в сегменте данных (а не стека, как с обычными внутренними переменными функций). Для удобства организации переходов переменную `i` начал вести в обратном порядке (от 100 до 0), т.к. значение самой переменной `i` нужно только для отсчета цикла и более нигде не используется. 
Статическую переменную `c` оптимизатор на каждой итерации цикла достает из оперативной памяти, прибавляет 1 и кладет обратно в оперативную память. Что с точки зрения эффективности кода явно медленная операция.

Еще стоит добавить, что раз статическая переменная лежит в сегменте данных, то она от глобальной отличается только областью видимости. В связи с этим использование таких переменных в многопоточном приложении создаст массу проблем и потребует взятия блокировок перед работой с ней.

На основании этого можно заключить, что статические переменные стоит использовать тогда, когда они действительно необходимы для реализации конкретного алгоритма

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо

Comment: @Mike 
>>Ваш цикл может передать какой нибудь вызываемой функции указатель на статическую переменную и через этот указатель к ней можно будет обращаться даже после завершения цикла.

За столь гениальное техническое решение стоит выдать премию. В виде предложения написать "по собственному"

Comment: @gbg А что вам не нравится в таком решении, статическая переменная в области данных, она там лежит постоянно. Если функцию и цикл запустить второй раз - они будут работать с той старой переменной даже не изменившей значения между вызовами. А если значение хочется поменять - то пожалуйста, меняйте на здоровье. Правда в таком случае ее было бы проще объявить глобальной, сути ее хранения это бы вообще не изменило, хотя выглядело бы более логичным, чем "по указателю" :)

Comment: @Mike, вы видели проект, в котором сотни модулей и миллионы строк кода? Так вот, появление в таком проекте глобальных сущностей, вроде статических переменных и глобальных переменных, замедляет отладку и внесение правок в сотни раз.

Причина - правку вносит не тот разраб, что эту лапшу замесил, а замесивший уже уволен. В итоге, сначала правящий должен изучить все тонкости (ага, всю диаграмму состояний глобальной сущности), а только потом править. В противном случае - глюкодром. Так что синглтоны и прочую глобальщину - в баню. С ними ни тестирование, ни рефакторинг гладко не идут.

Comment: @gbg Ну тогда надо избегать и статических переменных. А если их начали использовать (о этом и шла речь в вопросе), то чем они хуже глобальных.

Comment: @Mike - например тем, что засадит кто-нибудь такой счетчик куда-нибудь в метод класса вместо поля. А потом кто-то другой, нечаянно, такой класс в другом месте инстанцирует и метод вызовет. И поедет счетчик. Как такое западло потом искать - черт его знает.

Comment: @gbg Речь в вопросе шла про скорость работы и в общем то физическую организацию, в ответе я подчеркнул глобальность этой переменной, как раз указав что с ней можно работать всегда. Вопросов по поддержанию такого кода никто не ставил. Или вы предлагаете вместо ответа на конкретный вопрос отвечать "не делайте так никогда"

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, эти два фрагмента кода не эквивалентны.

В данном фрагменте кода

```
int c=0;
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) ++c;
```

переменная `c` имеет внешнюю область объявления по отношению к циклу.

В этом же фрагменте кода

```
for (int i=0;i<100;++i) {static int c;++c;}
```

переменная `c` имеет область объявления, соответствующей составному предложению цикла.

Поэтому семантически это два различных фрагмента кода.

Объявлять скалярную переменную как `static` внутри составного предложения цикла имеет смысл только в том случае, если управление программы несколько раз проходит через этот цикл, и вам надо подсчитать внутри цикла некоторую суммарную величину для всех активизаций цикла.

Но при этом имеет место проблема, что снаружи цикла эта переменная не видна. 
Поэтому трудно найти какое-то осмысленное применение данному подходу.

Разве что где-нибудь в рекурсивных функциях вы сможете найти такому трюку применение.

Говорить о какой-то высосанной из пальца оптимизации и сравнивать эти два фрагмента кода по единому критерию вообще бессмысленно.

Comment: Мне кстати вообще static этот не нравится. где его начальное значение ? компилятор не обязан обнулять переменные сам. Но и написать самому =0 то же вроде как нельзя

Comment: Я добавил ..., т.е. c мы можем использовать в самом теле for

Comment: @Mike static зануляет

Comment: @VladfromMoscow "Объявлять скалярную переменную как static внутри составного предложения цикла имеет смысл только в том случае, если управление программы несколько раз проходит через этот цикл, и вам надо подсчитать внутри цикла некоторую суммарную величину для всех активизаций цикла." - это именно этот случай

Comment: @Nokolay1979 Нет, это не тот случай, потому что в первом фрагменте кода эта переменная каждый раз обнуляется перед циклом.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow мы используем c и там и там локально в самом for; если хотите, можно в первом случае объявить c также в цикле, но с проверкой на !i

Comment: @Nokolay1979 Вопрос совершенно бессмысленный.

Comment: @Nokolay1979 В ваших циклах все, что делается с переменной c, это она инкрементируется. Поэтому совершенно не имеет значение, как объявлена переменная static или нет. Разница лишь в том, что в последнем случае заключительное значение нужно сохранить в статической памяти. Но это абсолютно никак не влияет на некую надуманную оптимизацию.

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, именно это мне и было нужно

Comment: @Nokolay1979: Подумайте, что будет, если ваш код будет использован рекурсивно или в многопоточном контексте. Ужаснитесь.